# textview animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I have the following requirement.

Initially I want to show the textview half on the screen. This textview when pulled out/clicked should show a complete one.

I just want few hints as to how to get over such animation.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use a translation on the X axis animation.
This should give you enough to start working on it:

```
    textview.setX(5000); //TODO: change to (current X + textview.witdh)
    textview.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(1000).start();
```

Comment: How can make the text come back and come on again?

Comment: Set the x to 0 back again and it will return to it's initial state